# consuming json values for collection view in table view iOS swift throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to consume json value and parse it to collection view inside table view while parsing getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception. Can anybody give suggestion where i went wrong?

here is my code

I have a class called `RemoteAPI`. Through that i am calling http url and requesting for json data

```
 class RemoteAPI
        {
     let url: NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://192.168.0.31:8097/api/asset/GetFile?username=username@gmail.com&RoleName=null&GroupName=null&EntityIdParam=1&StartIndex=1&EndIndex=300&PageIndex=0&PageSize=500&ItemsPerPage=1&Sort=0&EntityIdWithIndex=1&GName=null&GDesc=null&GId=null")!
                let ses = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                let task = ses.dataTaskWithURL(url,completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        return completionHandler(nil, error)
                    }

                    var err: NSError?
                    if(data != nil)
                    {
                   // let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as NSDictionary
                    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
                    if (err != nil)
                      {
                        println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                      }
                     }

                })
                task.resume()
            }
        }
```

At viewDidLoad func i am calling that api

```
override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //self.loadData()

            api.getData({data, error -> Void in
                if (data != nil) {
                    self.repositories = NSMutableArray(array: data)
                    self.tableView!.reloadData()

                }
                else {
                    println("api.getData failed")
                    println(error)
                }
            })

        }
```

i declared an array called repositories

```
 var repositories: NSMutableArray = []
```

Calling datasource and delegate function of collection view in table view `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as AssetTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width:50, height: 60)
        cell.collectionview.delegate = self
        cell.collectionview.dataSource = self
        cell.collectionview.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
```

At collection view `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I am trying to bind the parsed json values

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
        {
            var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? AssetCollectionViewCell
            if let navn = self.repositories[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? NSString
            {
                cell?.Assetname?.text = navn
            }

            else
            {
                cell?.Assetname?.text = "No Name"
            }

            if let desc = self.repositories[indexPath.row]["Description"] as? NSString
            {
                cell?.AssetDescription?.text = desc
            }

            return cell!
        }
```

Please give me some suggestion where i went wrong response status am getting 200 for my service but data which i am getting is out of scope.i noticed BAD_ACCESS  error is related to memory management but i am no getting how to resolve this issue .

This is my url data contains

```
 [
    {
    "$id":"1",
    "_Name":"Shared Assets",
    "_Description":"Shared Assets",
    "_rownum":"1",
    "_Id":"158",
    "_AppId_Fk":"15",
    "_EntityCode":"Shared Assets",
    "_EntityId":"0",
    "_EntityParentId":"1",
    "_CreatedDate":"11/25/2014 12:13:13 PM",
    "_ModifiedDate":"",
    "_Version":"1",
    "_LoginId":"ec2b3d5d-dcf0-452a-a735-fec16c287755",
    "_IsFolder":"True",
    "_FolderType":"1",
    "_EndIndex":" AS StartIndex,",
    "_OrderBy":"0",
    "_TotalNoOfPages":" AS CurrentPage,",
    "_IsGroup":" AS Sort,",
    "_SubName":"Shared Assets",
    "_pid":"158",
    "_NoOfAssets":"4",
    "_PageIndex":"1",
    "_TotalAssetPages":"1",
    "Name":"Shared Assets",
    "Description":"Shared Assets",
    "rownum":"1",
    "Id":"158",
    "AppId_Fk":"15",
    "EntityCode":"Shared Assets",
    "EntityId":"0",
    "EntityParentId":"1",
    "CreatedDate":"11/25/2014 12:13:13 PM",
    "ModifiedDate":"",
    "Version":"1",
    "LoginId":"ec2b3d5d-dcf0-452a-a735-fec16c287755",
    "IsFolder":"True",
    "FolderType":"1",
    "EndIndex":" AS StartIndex,",
    "OrderBy":"0",
    "TotalNoOfPages":" AS CurrentPage,",
    "IsGroup":" AS Sort,",
    "SubName":"Shared Assets",
    "pid":"158",
    "NoOfAssets":"4",
    "PageIndex":"1",
    "TotalAssetPages":"1",
    "Items":[
    {
    "$id":"2",
    "_gname":"Shared Assets",
    "_gisfolder":"True",
    "_gdesc":"Shared Assets",
    "_gid":"158",
    "_FileSize":"",
    "_EntityId":"3785",
    "_Name":"Vicoast ",
    "_LoginId":"ec2b3d5d-dcf0-452a-a735-fec16c287755",
    "_EntityParentId":"0",
    "_Description":"Office docs",
    "_AName":"",
    "_FileType":"",
    "_SubName":"Vicoast ",
    "_ExpiryDate":"",
    "_AssetPath":"",
    "_IsFolder":"True",
    "_GDescription":""
    }
    }
    ]
```

Anybody please go through my code and tell me what exactly i am missing?

Comment: Where is the error happening? What is the stack trace?

Comment: var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary here error throwing and data description am getting out of stack but response status will be 200

Comment: what does the error message says in the var err?

Comment: Are you receiving the data as unicode? NSJSONSerialization has a bug that is caused by the escaped unicode characters, the solution is to convert the escaped Unicode to real Unicode characters. Or could be a bad format JSON as well. I recomend you to add the JSON to your question

Comment: (NSData!) data = Some {
  Some = 0x3431203d20687467 {
    ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
  }
} this is description i am getting when i check at data

Comment: Just call the URL from your browser you should see the JSON there, it seems you are getting a empty result

Comment: My understand is that you cannot serialise the JSON, if is  because you have some invalid  char that is braking the serialisation, or invalid format, or data I cannot say until I see what you are trying to parse

Comment: Just edit your post and add all this new info there so make easier for someone else also help you

Comment: i edited it and please checekout now

Comment: As I expected your JSON has error, run it here (http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) the tool will show the errors to you

Comment: No json data is completely valid i checked by the given url

Comment: You have a very visible error in items, it is a array of items and you have "Items":[{} } you should have "Items":[{}] } in other worlds this array has not been close.

Comment: same reason i have a large amount of json data i didn't post complete json data just to show i pasted only some values but it is perfectly coming fine i don't have  problem with json data the one which u sent a link there only i checked

Comment: where i am getting error know at that thread it is showing get data swift implicitly unwrapped optional what does that mean?