# json data is coming null did i miss anything?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

```
class RemoteAPI
    {
        func getData(completionHandler: ((NSArray!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Void {
            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://192.168.0.31:8097/api/asset/GetFile?username=supreetha.shivananda@vicoast.com&RoleName=null&GroupName=null&EntityIdParam=1&StartIndex=1&EndIndex=300&PageIndex=0&PageSize=500&ItemsPerPage=1&Sort=0&EntityIdWithIndex=1&GName=null&GDesc=null&GId=null")!

            let ses = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = ses.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                println("Task completed")
                if (error != nil)
                {
                    return completionHandler(nil, error)
                }

                var err: NSError?
                if(data != nil)
                {
                    // let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as NSDictionary
                    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &err) as NSDictionary
                    if let unwrappedError = err
                    {
                        println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Through above function i am calling a json data and parsing it but when i run and debug the data is coming null

```
 let task = ses.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error ->
```

When i check the data and response i am getting values like 
Printing description of response:

```
(NSURLResponse!) response = Some {
  Some = 0x2030663666316632 {
    ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
  }
}
```

Printing description of data:

```
(NSData!) data = Some {
  Some = 0x726f636572202c7d {
    ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
  }
}
```

after that i am checking not null condition for data 
like

```
if(data != nil)
{
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &err) as NSDictionary
}
```

while doing json serialisation it is throwing EX_BAD_EXCEPTION

why i am getting null from json url? is that my way of approaching is wrong ? 
if i run the url i am getting json values at browser i am not getting whats going wrong can anybody please suggest me am struck into this

Comment: can you explain in detail? please didn't get yes actually later i am using json variable but didn't posted here before that while dataTaskwithurl there only i am getting value nil for data and even for response

Comment: if u didn't get go through this link posted neatly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454425/consuming-json-values-for-collection-view-in-table-view-ios-swift-throwing-exc-b?noredirect=1#comment48992774_30454425

Comment: You are not get an empty result but probably a JSON with bad format

Comment: http://192.168.0.31:8097/api/asset/GetFile?username=supreetha.shivananda@vicoast.com&RoleName=null&GroupName=null&EntityIdParam=1&StartIndex=1&EndIndex=300&PageIndex=0&PageSize=500&ItemsPerPage=1&Sort=0&EntityIdWithIndex=1&GName=null&GDesc=null&GId=null

Comment: please go through that url and validate it is is perfectly correct

Comment: hello icaro can u able to share your gmail i can explain you my problem though chat it will be more helpful for me to share your knowledge and i will educate my self on iOS development

Comment: Yes I can try help you tomorrow as it is very late here now, but mean while have a look in your items array it seems to be missing the "]" from the end of the array.

Comment: hello icaro u there?

Comment: hello icaro u told me that u will help me in sharing knowledge of iOS R u there

Comment: Hey, sorry I have been really busy, send me a copy of your JSON (full) and I will have a look for you, just add in some sharing site and add the link in your question or here, but you need to send me the full json so I can help you

Comment: no that i have done :-) i got that result thank you in general if i get some doubts mean time i want somebodys help to meet the deadline so asking ur gmail or fb id

Comment: Just post your questions on the site and we all gonna help you. What was the problem with the Json? If none of the question solved your problem you should post the answer here so other people can learn from it, and also check an answer as correct even if yours so the question get closed

Comment: hmm okie i will post it

Answer (score 0):

I doubt wether your response format is corrector not. Try this.

```
if(data != nil) {
    // let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as NSDictionary
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &err) as? AnyObject
    if let unwrappedError = err {
           println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
    }
    if json is [AnyObject] {
        println("The response is array")
     }
     if json is [String:AnyObject] {
        println("The response is dictionary")
    }
  }
```